# how to pass array of model from one actvtiy to another in android

Tags: android

```
public class DataModel implements Serializable, Parcelable {

    /**  */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4861597073026532544L;

    private String cid;
    private String name;


    /**
     * @return the cid
     */
    public String getCid() {
        return cid;
    }

    /**
     * @param cid
     *            the cid to set
     */
    public void setCid(String cid) {
        this.cid = cid;
    }


    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name
     *            the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }




    public DataModel(Parcel in) {
        super();
        readFromParcel(in);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<DataModel> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<DataModel>() {
        public DataModel createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new DataModel(in);
        }

        public DataModel[] newArray(int size) {

            return new DataModel[size];
        }

    };

    public void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        String[] result = new String[23];
        in.readStringArray(result);

        this.cid = result[0];
        this.name = result[1];


    }

    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeStringArray(new String[] { this.cid,
                this.name});

    }}
```

this is my Datamodel:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DataModel _modeDataModel=new DataModel(MainActivity.this);
        _modeDataModel.setCid("1");
        _modeDataModel.setName("Anil");


        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelableArrayList("channel",(ArrayList<DataModel>) model);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

}
```

main activtiy

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Bundle getBundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        List<DataModel> channelsList = getBundle.getParcelableArrayList("channel");
    }
}
```

second actvity

i want to pass data between one activity to another activity from One List but i am unable to set value  model also unable to send one activity to another there is compile time Error is coming please suggest me where am doing mistake and ho to send data from one activity to another ,

Comment: You have lots of errors, "model" what is that? You create a model with the name "_modeDataModel". Then, why send an ArrayList when you only want to send a model?

Comment: Please suggest me how to set value and how to pass it i just setting one static value name and id for example @Carnal

Comment: Look at my answer

Comment: Error is coming  DataModel _modeDataModel=new DataModel(MainActivity.this);  and  also bundle.putParcelableArrayList("channel",(ArrayList<DataModel>) model);

Answer (score 0):

```
     ArrayList<DataModel> modelArrayList = new ArrayList<>(); //Use your model array here
     DataModel _modeDataModel=new DataModel(MainActivity.this);
    _modeDataModel.setCid("1");
    _modeDataModel.setName("Anil");
     modelArrayList.add(_modeDataModel);

     //Call like this way
     Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putExtra("channel", modelArrayList);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);  


      public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                Bundle getBundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
                ArrayList<DataModel> channelsList = (ArrayList<DataModel>) getBundle.getParcelableArrayList("channel");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Error is coming in first Actvity not in Second how to set value and how to pass there i am getting Error @Jd Prajapa

Comment: how to set some Value in datamodel

Comment: why you are using array?

Comment: Look we have to sent some static data so i want to know how to set some value ArrayList<DataModel> data

Comment: add your DataModel object in list... simple

Comment: i am unable to create Object of Datamodel @Jd Prajapati

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139586/discussion-between-maklee-lee-and-jd-prajapati).

Answer (score 0):

To send in first activity:

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable("channel", _modeDataModel);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(intent);
```

To retrieve in second activity:

```
    Bundle getBundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    DataModel model = getBundle.getParcelable("channel");
```

Comment: But i am unable to set value when i create object then i am getting Error 
        DataModel _modeDataModel=new DataModel();  no Constructor

Comment: we have to pass List<Datamodel> obj; not DataModel obj @Carnal

Answer (score 0):

you create Datamodel in this way :

```
 DataModel _modeDataModel=new DataModel(MainActivity.this);
```

but DataModel class does not have constructor that accept an Activity !

add this constructor to your DataModelClass

```
public DataModel(Activity activity){

}
```

Or Change That line to this :

```
 DataModel _modeDataModel=new DataModel();
```

after all send Arrays of Datamodel to another Activity Like this :

```
ArrayList<DataModel> array = new ArrayList<>;

 DataModel _modeDataModel=new DataModel();
 _modeDataModel.setCid("1");
 _modeDataModel.setName("Anil");
array.add(_modeDataModel);
//Add any number you want

 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
 intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("Key",array);
 startActivity(intent);
```

and in SecondActivity :

```
ArrayList<DataModel> array2 = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("Key");
```

I hope to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Change your MainActivity to this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DataModel _modeDataModel=new DataModel();
        _modeDataModel.setCid("1");
        _modeDataModel.setName("Anil");

        ArrayList<DataModel> dataModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        dataModelList.add(_modeDataModel);


        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelableArrayList("channel",dataModelList);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

and in your DataModel, change String length to 2 in readFromParcel method:-

```
public void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        String[] result = new String[2];  
        in.readStringArray(result);

        this.cid = result[0];
        this.name = result[1];


    }
```

and add an empty parameter constructor to DataModel:-

```
public DataModel() {
        super();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass ArrayList of model object using Serializable try with below model class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

    public class DataModel implements Serializable {

        /**  */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 4861597073026532544L;

        private String cid;
        private String name;

        public String getCid() {
            return cid;
        }

        public void setCid(String cid) {
            this.cid = cid;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
```

Start Acivity:

```
 DataModel dataModel = new DataModel();
 dataModel.setCid("1");
 dataModel.setName("User");
 ArrayList<DataModel> models = new ArrayList<>();
 models.add(dataModel);

 Intent intent=new new  Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
  intent.putExtra("data",models);
  startActivity(intent);
```

Second Activity:

```
  ArrayList<DataModel> data = new ArrayList<>();
  data.addAll((ArrayList<DataModel>)  getIntent().getSerializableExtra("data"));
```